# Does a recursive playthrough have a different ending?

Tags: transistor

When I beat the Steam version of Transistor, it gave me the `Bye()` achievement. I noticed that there is also a `Goodbye()` achievement which is awarded when you complete the game via recursion (New Game+).

Is the ending cutscene of a recursive playthrough different?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

People on the Steam discussion board say that [the ending does not change](https://steamcommunity.com/app/237930/discussions/0/540742485528592744/).

There are a few [differences listed on the wiki](http://transistor.wikia.com/wiki/Recursion). Most of them are gameplay-related. The only ones listed that apply to the story are:

> - The opening line from the Transistor ("Hey Red... We're not getting away with this, are we?"), is spoken by Royce Bracket, instead of the usual Transistor narrator.
> - In the Process encounter which normally starts the Turn() tutorial, the tutorial glitches, spamming the "Recommended Move" Arrow across the screen, before a short "restart" of the Turn() flashes, allowing the player to use the Turn() however they see fit.
> - The work of the Process (turning Cloudbank into the White Canvas) is shown much stronger. For instance, the room where the first Jerk is fought is already heavily distorted, almost two-thirds of the room already painted white.

Comment: I can confirm that the ending does not change. Apart from a few small changes that you mentioned, the story does not change.